# ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream in Jboss 7 always returns null

Tags: classloader, jboss7.x

I have one my.sar file, structure defined is as follows

my.sar

|

|

|---------META-INF

|         |

|         |-----------------------jboss-deployment-structure.xml

|         |-----------------------jboss-service.xml

in jboss-deployment-structure.xml i have added multiple jar dependencies required by mbean classes defined under jboss-service.xml....

Now my dependant class (referred by jar - `JBOSS-7-HOME/modules`) is referring to xml file by using below code,

```
Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
ClassLoader contextClassLoader = thread.getContextClassLoader(); 
InputStream in = contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(<xmlFileName>);
```

but this above code is unable to find xml file... It always returns `null`.

Could anybody help me to find out where to place required xml files so that class can find those xml files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<resource-root path="."/>
```

to the module.xml of the module that loads the XML and put the XML-files to the module directory (where the module.xml is).